# Redis connection with Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, redis, promise

I wrote a function to connect to a redis instance. It works but I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do what I wanted to achieve.

The goal was to have a class with a `connect()` function which would return a Promise that would resolve to `true` if the connection was successful. So in the end I wanted to be able to run
`await someClass.connect()` where `someClass` would be the class that contains the redis client.

This is the code in Typescript:

```
async connect(): Promise<boolean> {
    this.client = redis.createClient({ host: 'session-store' });

    const connectionPromise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        if(!this.client) return reject();

        this.client.on('error', err => {
            return reject(err);
        })

        this.client.on('connect', () => {
            return resolve(true);
        })
    });

    this.client.on('error', err => {
        throw err;
    });

    return connectionPromise;
}
```

Is this the correct way to achieve the described behaviour? I feel like I am overlooking something but I don't know what it is and the code works as far as I tested it.

Comment: Everything in your code looks pretty sensible, except the `throw err` thing -- not show what you're expecting to happen with that

Comment: I would also adjust your initial rejection to return a better error message, if you have one. `if(!this.client) return reject(new Error('what would cause this.client to be false?'));`

Comment: @TKoL as far as I understand, the `on('error')` listener should throw every time redis encounters an error, also for the requests following the connection. 
Good point about the error in the first rejection - I will think about it. To be honest I don't even know what would cause this.client to be false but Typescript would have marked it as an error if I didn't include that check so there must be something.

Comment: `listener should throw every time redis encounters an error` - yes, but throw what to where? By the time it hits the `on error` callback, that promise will have already resolved, so ... where is the error being thrown to? What do you imagine is going to catch the error? Or are you throwing it because you don't want it to be caught?